# Can we update contents of a specific file in Amazon S3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using AWS PHP SDK. I uploaded a JSON file to S3 bucket. Now I would like to get the file contents(*uploaded to S3 bucket*), add some additional text to the grabbed file contents and update that file over the S3 bucket.

What I want is something like this:

1. file name: `userlist.json`
2. grab content of file using S3 provide methods
3. eg: existing file contents are `{'abc','xyz'}`
4. add additional contents `{'abc','xyz'}, {'zxv','opiv','cvpo'}`
5. update newly added content into S3 bucket file (`userlist.json`)

How we can do this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't add data to, or modify just part of an existing s3 object, you need to read the object, make changes to the object, and the write the entire object back to s3.

Comment: Can you tell me how we can do this ? while uploading the same name file, would it replace ? I thought it will give me an error, that file is already exits.

Comment: It will just replace the existing object (file).

Comment: If you need to keep history of the S3 object, you can turn on versioning in the S3 management console. [Managing Versioning in S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-versioning.html). Note that I *believe* that you pay for total storage. That is, you pay for each version of each S3 object that you keep.

Comment: How do you solve the race condition when multiple threads update simultaneously? E.g.: both threads read the content, then both threads modify the content, then both threads write the content. The modification that gets written first is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite any file in s3.
When you write file in same location with same name then it remove old file and replace it with new one.

Comment: can you provide the code or any helping link? So I can perform this action ?

Comment: use sdk for this purpose http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpPHP.html for php sdk

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following algorithm

step 1 : get the file content from a specific bucket using the function

```
return $result = $this->s3->getObject(array(
        'Bucket' => bucket,            
        'Key' => 'file_name'
    ));
```

step 2: Write the return content in a local file.

step 3: Read the file and modify whatever you like. Save the file in local machine. Here you can save the file in different extension.

step 4: Upload the file in the desired bucket. Remember it s3 bucket shall not give immediate update if you overwrite the file with same name.

step 5:End